# How can I find where my coding error is from this "Debug Assertion Failed!" error?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I just ran my code through the terminal and a "Debug Assertion Failed!" error popped up that says "vector subscript out of range". This is the first time I've ever encountered this kind of error, so I'm not sure how to find where the error is in my code. Perhaps it is something obvious since I'm pretty new to C++, and I'm not very good at finding where errors are. Below is the code I have, so please let me know if you find what needs to be corrected. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* right, * down;
};

Node* construct(vector<vector<int>> arr, size_t i, size_t j, size_t m, size_t n)
{
    if (i > n - 1 || j > m - 1)
        return NULL;
    Node * temp = new Node();
    temp->data = arr[i][j];
    temp->right = construct(arr, i, j + 1, m, n);
    temp->down = construct(arr, i + 1, j, m, n);
    return temp;
}

void display(Node * head)
{
    Node* Rp;

    Node* Dp = head;

    // loop till node->down is not NULL 
    while (Dp) {
        Rp = Dp;

        // loop till node->right is not NULL 
        while (Rp) {
            cout << Rp->data << " ";
            Rp = Rp->right;
        }
        cout << "\n";
        Dp = Dp->down;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


    if ((argc == 2) && (string(argv[1]) == "-Stack"))
    {
        int K;
        cin >> K; //getting the number of rooms from the text file



        for (int i = 0; i < K; ++i) //a loop for each room
        {
            int M = 0; // initializing rows variable
            int N = 0; // initializing columns variable
            cin >> M >> N;


            vector<vector<int> > matrix(M); //give a matrix with a dimension M*N with all elements set to 0
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
                matrix[i].resize(N);

            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) //adding each row to the matrix
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) //adding each column to the matrix
                {
                    cin >> matrix[i][j]; //putting all the elements in the matrix
                }
            }

            size_t m = M, n = N;
            Node* head = construct(matrix, 0, 0, m, n);
            display(head);
            return 0;

        }

    }
    else if ((argc == 2) && (string(argv[1]) == "-Queue"))
    {
        int K;
        cin >> K; //this grabs the number of rooms in the dungeon
        cout << K;
    }
}
```

Comment: Run it inside a debugger and check the call stack.

Comment: If this is Visual Stuido, break into the debugger and use the Stack Frame combo box (should be on the toolbar when debugging) to switch to the line of your code that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of runtime errors do not happen exactly where the error originated, but somewhere after that with the aid of the debugging tools you use.

For example, if you attempt to write to a `std::vector` past its size, then the debugging version of it might have bounds checking and throw an exception on that (debuggers also insert stack frame traps to check buffer overruns etc).

This exception does not occur at the precise line of the error, but at the code that follows.

You use the *Call Stack* feature of the debugger, to find exactly where the error is.

Example:

```
vector<int> x(10);
x[10] = 1; // Calls vector::operator[] 
     // in vector::operator[]
     if(i >= size())
          throw; // This is where the exception is thrown
```

The call stack would help you go from the `throw` line to the `x[10] = 1` line in which the error originated.

Comment: Ok I've read that I can access the call stack while it is debugging, however my debugging take about one second to complete so I don't have time to find the call stack feature... is there another way to access it? I am using Visual Studio Community by the way.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant, what does it mean that your debugging takes one second to complete? When an exception occurs, program stops.

Comment: Hmm well when I run the debugger, I don't get any errors. I only got the error when I ran my code using the necessary command.

Comment: Run your code with that command *inside* the debugger. If it's a command line, then pass it through Visual studio options.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you possibly walk me through this perhaps?